# How to get two dimentional array max size if different lengths

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to set my array size in dynamically. Here my input values array values are

```
int[][] dubArr={{2,5,6},{2,5,4,7}};
```

I want to set my array size

```
int[][] size=new int[dubArr.length][dubArray[0].length];
```

but problem is here i cant store my second array last value

dont say `[dubArray[1].length]` ;

Comment: Do you simply need a copy of the original array or do you explicitly want to make the array square? If you only need a copy, making it square in the process might not be a good idea because you are adding extra values.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the maximum length of the second dimension and creating the new array in a single line makes the array square, so you lose information about its shape. So I suppose that what you really want is a deep-copy of the original array in its original shape:

```
if (dubArr == null) {
    return null;
}
final int[][] size = new int[dubArr.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < dubArr.length; i++) {
    size[i] = dubArr[i].clone();
}
return size;
```

This will work even if `dubArr` is `null` or empty.

Comment: You may also use `size[i] = dubArr[i].clone()`.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Yes, that's better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Java8):

```
    int[][] dubArr={{2,5,6},{2,5,4,7}};
    int[][] size =new int[dubArr.length][Stream.of(dubArr).mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().getAsInt()];
```